# React Native Web SEO Optimization

Tags: seo, google-search-console, local-seo

I am trying to better optimize my **react-native** web app project for the internet. I have it built successfully and launched on the internet. I had originally created this project as an app and have switched towards web as it is easy to create two versions for both applications... *Hence why I chose react-native*

I am now trying to make my website search engine optimized. I am realizing that **react-router** is something that I should have been using potentially as it will map out the site to google bots.

I have created it using the **react-navigation/drawer**, along with two **react-navigation/native-stacks**. These are all for navigation purposes implemented in which work fine on the web.

The react router appears to be a native react module not a react-native module, should I switch my project over to the react-router form for better SEO?

Does react native have its own form of this or a hook for **navigation-container**?

Comment: you may want to explore Expo Router v2 soon, it looks promising as it will be more SEO-friendly. It was recently been announced: https://twitter.com/Baconbrix/status/1656634363847507968